# Multiprocessing pool throws "too many open files"

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I am using python's multiprocessing.Pool for parallel computation. I use map/imap for delegating a list of ~400 arguments to my worker function using 20 processes (having 36 CPUs). The process is iterative and executes for let's say 100 times. I used `spawn` since my execution got frozen otherwise when using large data in my worker while using `fork`.

```
import torch
from scipy.spatial.distance import mahalanobis


def calc(args):
    dim_selected, pos_embeddings, neg_embeddings = args

    I = torch.eye(len(dim_selected))
    max_dist = []
    
    N, C, HW = pos_embeddings.size()
    N, C, HW = neg_embeddings.size()

    for p in range(HW):
        mean_neg = torch.mean(neg_embeddings[:, :, p], dim=0)
        cov_neg = torch.cov(neg_embeddings[:, :, p].T)
        covI = torch.inverse(cov_neg + 0.01 * I)
        max_dist.append(max([mahalanobis(p_sample, mean_neg, VI=covI) for p_sample in pos_embeddings[:, :, p]]))
    
    return dim_selected[-1], max(max_dist)

# N D-dimensional embeddings of P patches
# pos_embeddings = torch.rand(N, D, P)
# neg_embeddings = torch.rand(N, D, P)

C=100
dim_candidates = list(range(C))
best_dims = []

dargs = [(d, pos_embeddings[:, d, :], neg_embeddings[:, d, :]) for d in [best_dims+[dc] for dc in dim_candidates]]
with multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Pool(n_workers) as pool:
   for i in range(C):
      print(f"Iteration {i+1}")
      print("Number of tasks to be executed (number of candidates):", len(dargs))
      results = tqdm(pool.imap(calc, darg))
      # gather return values
      new_d, dim_scores = zip(*results)
      # remove 'best dimension' from candidates
      # ...
```

Executing this, I get after 300 arguments `OSError: too many open files`, which possibly means that too many processes have spawned. Can someon help me out, since I have tried a lot of things (splitting my argument list in smaller parts, moving the pool instantiation inside the loop, calling garbage collector, calling `join()`), but there was no improvement. Do I understand something wrong about how `Pool` terminates the process sockets here?

Comment: Is the value of n_workers 20? If so, how many CPUs do you have available? What does calc() do (in detail)? If you were using fork then presumably you're on a POSIX type system and, if you are, then you should be using fork (the default) for optimum performance

Comment: You'll probably need to post the full code

Comment: `darg` is undefined.

Comment: @rasjani linux debian.

Comment: @DarkKnight yes, i had problems using fork since execution froze and nothing was executed when dealing with large files. Calc basically does matrix operations using torch and calculates distances of certain feature dimensions to a given estimated distribution. It returns the 'best-separating' combination of dimensions

Comment: @rasjani ```ulimit -n``` gives me 1024, Error occurs at 300 so i don't think that is the problem